# SQL Server/Access Connection Ongoing Maintenance on Different Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, server

I am working on building a database through SQL Server.  I am going to link it to Microsoft Access so that others can easily view and manipulate the data.

I am only at this place for a temporary amount of time, so I need to make sure that someone else in the office can maintain the database once I am gone.  If I am only able to use my own personal computer server, is there any way for me to send the entirety of my work to someone else?  Or will they have to recreate everything on their own server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How best to copy entire databases in MS SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79669/how-best-to-copy-entire-databases-in-ms-sql-server)

Comment: The Access frontend can simply be copied, then the tables need to be relinked from the new server.